# LIve Visual Tree not visible when debugging a Android app

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I am running the latest version of Visual Studio Community edition (17.5.4) and debugging a blank MAUI app.  When the app is run for for Anroid (Pixel 5, Android 13) the Live Visual Tree does not appear.  However it does appear if I run it as a Windows app.

XAML Hot reloading has also been enabled under the debug settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don’t know if any of this will fix, but here are some ideas to get VS and app to a clean state: Close VS. Manually delete app from device or emulator. Delete project’s hidden .VS folder, and all .bin and .obj folders. Run VS again, and launch app from VS with debugging. Fixed?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This did not work unfortunately, would you happen to know the best place to report this issue to the relevant team?

Comment: @MusaffarPatel You can report this problem in the Visual studio directly. Please see this document about [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)